# What's wrong with the following Rust code to print each element of array?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rest and learning it from "Rust Essential Training" on Linkedin Learning. At the end of chapter 5 (Program Flow and Control), I got the following question as a chapter quiz.

> What's wrong with the following code to print each element of `my_array`?
>
> ```rust
> fn main() {
>    let my_array = [1, 2, 3];
>
>    for element in my_array {
>        println!("element is {}", element);
>    }
> }
> ```

I couldn't think of anything wrong with it, and when I ran it on visual code, it did run without any problem, yet they said

> The for loop cannot iterate over `my_array` directly.
>
> > This program needs to use `my_array.iter()` to get an iterator over the array.

Can someone give me a meaningful explanation? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Their example is outdated. On newer versions of Rust, arrays can be iterated over directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[It actually works just fine on the newest versions of Rust (1.53 and higher)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2021/IntoIterator-for-arrays.html). You can see for yourself [on the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6e01cf390beb951217657771438e06a5).

Prior to 1.53, this didn't work, because arrays themselves did not implement `IntoIterator`. As of Rust 1.53, somewhat confusingly, *all* editions of Rust actually implement `IntoIterator` for arrays, but:

1. On all editions, direct iteration is consuming (since it was illegal before, there's no risk of a compatibility break)
2. On Rust 2021+, calling `.into_iter()` on an array is equivalent to direct iteration (it consumes)
3. On Rust 2015 & 2018, `.into_iter()` is equivalent to calling `.iter()` (non-consuming iteration by reference) or more strictly, `array.into_iter()` resolves to `(&array).into_iter()`, and converting the array *reference* to an iterator makes a non-consuming iterator backed by the array.

The distinction between editions is due to a "small hack" that makes it so, even though arrays implement `IntoIterator` on all editions as of 1.53, on 2015 & 2018, the compiler hides this fact solely for the case of `.into_iter()` method call syntax on arrays, so it instead resolves to `(&array).into_iter()` (which is what happened back when arrays did not implement `IntoIterator` at all). It's a hack, because it defends against method call syntax alone; any other means of iterating the array (e.g. direct iteration, `iter.zip`, directly invoking `IntoIterator::into_iter` on the array) will find it's an `IntoIterator` and iterate it by (consuming) value, but none of those methods worked prior to 1.53 anyway, so no existing code was relying on them (compiling `array.into_iter()` on Rust 2015 or 2018 will [emit a loud warning that the meaning changes in Rust 2021](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=640f0318512c2f08b082186f228706f6)).

Prior to 1.53 you had to be explicitly convert to an array reference/slice (which do support iteration), or explicitly call `.iter()` or `.into_iter()` on the array (the latter of which is still non-consuming, resolving to `(&array).into_iter()`; this is why the hack was needed, so the new feature didn't change the behavior in existing code for 2015 & 2018).

Mind you, in this particular case, the elements of *your* array implement `Copy`, so the array contents are not consumed no matter how it's iterated; the only distinction is whether you're iterating over references to integer or over integer values. But for non-`Copy` types, the distinction between consuming the actual values and merely "viewing" by reference is important.

Comment: Thank you so much for the link and your explanation.

Comment: I just noticed how fantastic the "Rust playground" is. I can't thank you enough for including it in your answer. I will use it a lot for HIR, ASM, and MIR.  Thank you again.

Comment: @Hanoch: Yeah, the playground is pretty magical. You're welcome!

Comment: This is exactly the opposite: since Rust version 1.53, this code (direct iteration) _always_ works. What changes between editions is explicit `into_iter()`: it is equivalent to direct iteration in edition 2021, and to `iter()` in older editions using the abovementioned hack.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: You are correct, I initially misread (and have now rewritten).

Comment: This is still incorrect: direct iteration, on _all_ editions, is consuming since 1.53.0. What changes is `into_iter()`: it is equivalent to direct iteration in edition 2021, and to `iter()` (non-consuming) in prior editions.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman: Okay, I reread your comments and the explanation I linked multiple times, and I *think* it's now 100% correct. Pre-1.53 people often wrote `.into_iter()` (even though it gained them nothing over `.iter()`) and it worked (in a non-consuming fashion), because it resolved to `(&array).into_iter()`. The hack in 1.53 exists to avoid breaking pre-1.53 code by making Rust 2015 & 2018 continue to treat that code the same way, *even though* arrays now implement `IntoIterator`. In Rust 2021, `array.into_iter()` resolves directly on the array, and consumes. Thanks for the corrections!

Comment: Yes, not it is correct.